# Sitecore - Multiple-Site Error Page Handling

Tags: error-handling, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a multiple-site Sitecore project. I know how to deal with error pages via the webconfig's ErrorPage, ItemNotFoundUrl, LayoutNotFoundUrl, LinkItemNotFoundUrl for one site.

However, I'm wanting to display a different error pages for each site. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

In any case, you can probably store the URLs of the error pages for each site as attributes of the `/configuration/sitecore/sites/site` elements in web.config by extending the `Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext` class ([see for information about extending existing classes](http://www.sitecore.net/en/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Extend-Classes-Provided-by-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)).

The [SDN forum post](http://sdn.sitecore.net/forum//ShowPost.aspx?PostID=30233) provides more information specifically about the 404 `/ItemNotFound` condition, including an example of an extension of `Sitecore.SItes.SiteContext`.

For `ItemNotFoundUrl`, I think it depends on whether you use an item or a file as the 404 page. If you handle 404 with items, then after the item resolver, add a processor to the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline to set the context item to the 404 item for that site if the context item is null. If you use files, then I think override `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest.HandleItemNotFound()` and `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler.DoProcessRequest()` and update the corresponding references in the web.config file.

For `ErrorPage`, I think you would have to override `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderLayout.SecurityCheck.Process` and update the corresponding reference in web.config.

For `LayoutNotFoundUrl`, I think you would have to override `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest.HandleLayoutNotFound`, and update the corresponding reference in web.config.

For `LinkItemNotFoundUrl`, I would probably add a processor to the renderField pipeline to perform replacement of the default value of the setting with the value that applies for the context site.

If this is a common requirement, we should turn it into a Sitecore Shared Source project, or add it to an existing project.

Answer (score 4):

There's an [entry in the SDN scrapbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Handle%20404%20errors.aspx) about how to do this for a multi-site install.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Shared Source project which should fit the requirements is most parts. It's called [Sitecore Error Manager](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Error_Manager.aspx).

Hope that helps.