# Sitecore Config files for MultiSite Solution

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

We have a MultiSite solution using Sitecore 7.1 .
I want to use custom config files for different Sites. For example i have a different CustomLink Provider for Sites , Different 404 pages , Different Language Resolver .

How should i add or patch these config files and in what order ????

Any help

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a different web.config for each site but there are techniques you can apply to make things easier:

I've written some blog posts that address just this topic:

- [A Switching Link Provider in Sitecore](http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/a-switching-link-provider.html)
- [Create Site Specific
  Pipeline Processors for Sitecore](http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/site-specific-pipeline-processors.html)

Here are some others that you may find useful:

- [Site-Specific Providers](http://nttdatasitecore.com/Blog/2014/February/Site-Specific-Providers.aspx)
- [Sitecore Pipeline Enabled LinkProvider](http://thegrumpycoder.com/post/78684655662/sitecore-pipeline-enabled-linkprovider)
- [Sitecore - Multiple-Site Error Page Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128197/sitecore-multiple-site-error-page-handling)

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to do this with configuration files you would have to set up multiple content delivery sites. You would then deploy different configuration files to the different environments so that they would use your custom code and configurations.  Each website 'site' definition would be pointed to a different root in the common Sitecore database.

This would require a scaled model with multiple licenses. If that's not possible, I recommend going with @TwentyGotoTen's approach for supporting the multi-site within a single website.